# Signal for M2M changed on a through field

Tags: django, many-to-many, has-many-through, django-signals

Before switching my M2M field to a through field I had this signal that would call methods on the instance to update some of its values. But I switched to a 'through' type M2M and it stopped functioning. I have a work around by calling those functions in my serializer, but that is kind of nasty. How do I fix it?

**Signal**

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Order.items.through)
def update_order_when_items_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.set_weight()
    instance.set_total_price()
    instance.save()
```

**Current Models**

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('main.Order')
    item = models.ForeignKey('main.Item')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("main.ShopUser")
    items = models.ManyToManyField("main.Item", through='main.OrderItem')
    placed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_placed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: `.items.through` is only available on an *instance* of `Order`

Comment: That was working when `order.items` was just a M2M field without a `through` model

Comment: Huh. That's interesting. I'll have to set that up and see how that worked sometime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel silly for not figuring this out before. Instead of m2m_changed signal use the `post_save` and `post_delete` on the through model and it should essentially do the same thing. Then in my serializer just remove the `instance.save()` if I am not doing other changes.

```
@receiver((post_save, post_delete), sender="main.OrderItem")
def update_order_when_items_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.order.set_weight()
    instance.order.set_total_price()
    instance.order.save()
```